# Por que mi script no se ejecuta en un proyecto de angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Soy nuevo en angular y tengo el siguiente codigo:

/**home.component.html**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let d = new Date();
        document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Time right now is:  " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds()
        "</h1>"
        </script>
    <header>
        <h1>Mi sitio web</h1>
    </header>
    <p>
        Favor compartir esta informacion con
        <b>Equipo de trabajo</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        le invitamos a participar de la <i>serie de webinars</i>
    </p>
    <p>Contactenos</p>
    <p><s>telefono: 77785888</s></p>
    <p><strong>Telefono nuevo:  77744144</strong></p>
    <small>
        Todos los derechos reservados
        copyright @2019
    </small>
</body>
```

Lo que pasa es que la parte del **script** no se ejecuta en el proyecto de Angular, mientras en un proyecto normal que no es de angular se ejecuta normalmente, quisiera saber como poder hacer funcionar el script.

Comment: Entre muchos otros detalles, angular usa TypeScript como meta lenguaje para luego compilar a JavaScript, dado eso escribir directo código de JS no creo funcione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Poner lo de tu meta de script en el archivo .ts del componente.
2. Crear un nuevo documento con extensión .ts y llamarlo en tu componente.